# What is the shelf life of my syrup?

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime, syrup

This is a continuation of my [last question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/29594/7275).

the recipe I have is:

> 2 1/2 cups water 
> 2 cups white sugar 
> 3/4 cup brown sugar 
> 1 moist vanilla bean, preferably Mexican or Bourbon (Madagascar)
>
> Combine the sugars and water in a saucepan.
>
> Boil for at least 10 minutes.
>
> Let cool. When solution has cooled, add the extract and stir well.

After I make my syrup, how long of a shelf life does it have? Do I need to refrigerate it, or can I keep it on my countertop?